# ZioHttp end point - Return json response

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test, zio-http, zio-json

I am creating a ZioHttp Rest endpoint...

For a Json request I want to return Json response ...

I'm able to retrun logs, print lines but not sure how to return json response...

Here's my code:

```
import zio.{Console, _}
import zhttp._
import zhttp.http._
import zhttp.service.Server
import zio.json.{DeriveJsonEncoder, JsonEncoder}

//import java.io.Console


object ZioHttp extends ZIOAppDefault {


  val port = 9000


  val app: Http[Any, Nothing, Request, Response] = Http.collect[Request] {
    case Method.GET -> !! / "zioCollector" => Response.text("Hello, Http server This is Mohammed Mukhtar Ali!!")
  }

  case class Events(experimentId: String,
                    variantId: String,
                    accountId: String,
                    deviceId: String,
                    date: Int)

  object Events {
    implicit val encoder: JsonEncoder[Events] = DeriveJsonEncoder.gen[Events]
  }

  val zApp: UHttpApp = Http.collectZIO[Request] {
    case Method.POST -> !! / "zioCollector" =>
      Random.nextIntBetween(3, 5).map(n => Response.text("Hello " * n + "server2!"))
  }

  //  val zApp2: UHttpApp = Http.collectZIO[Request] {
  //    case Method.POST -> !! / "zioCollector" =>
  //      Random.nextIntBetween(3, 5).map(n => Response.json()
  //  }

  val combied = app ++ zApp


  val httpProgram = for {
    _ <- Console.printLine(s"Starting server at http://localhost:$port")
    _ <- Server.start(port, combied)
  } yield ()


  override def run = httpProgram

}
```

I'm a beginner with Zio and scala, appreatiate any help proided!

Comment: Pretty sure this is covered in the documentation. If I had to guess, I would look to replace `Response.text` with something else.

Comment: could you add any link pls? I can't read?  

Comment: Have you tried `Response.json(events.toJson)` yet?

Comment: Hey Andriy, so basically something like below answer (please see my reply below) but with this we are explicitly passing Json values... I want something like (each time when the endpoint is hit use that json  in code like a Generic record to write to a Kafka topic ) Appreciate  your help!

Comment: I want the json body in code...each time when the endpoint is hit..

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert for zio-http (nor zio in general), but this code works for me:

```
import zhttp.*
import zhttp.http.*
import zhttp.service.Server
import zio.json.*
import zio.Console
import zio.*



object ZioHttp extends ZIOAppDefault {

  val port = 9000

  case class Events(
    experimentId: String,
    variantId: String,
    accountId: String,
    deviceId: String,
    date: Int
  )

  object Events {
    implicit val encoder: JsonEncoder[Events] = DeriveJsonEncoder.gen[Events]
  }

  val exampleEvents =
    Events(
      "someExperimentId",
      "someVariantId",
      "someAccountId",
      "someDeviceId",
      42
    )

  val zApp: UHttpApp = Http.collectZIO[Request] {
    case Method.GET -> !! / "exampleEvents" =>
      ZIO.succeed(Response.json(exampleEvents.toJson))
  }


  val httpProgram = for {
    _ <- Console.printLine(s"Starting server at http://localhost:$port")
    _ <- Server.start(port, zApp)
  } yield ()


  override def run = httpProgram

}
```

Comment: Hey Martin, So basically i don't want to pass 

` val exampleEvents =
    Events(
      "someExperimentId",
      "someVariantId",
      "someAccountId",
      "someDeviceId",
      42
    )
` 

When I hit endpoint with a json ( example : posting using Postman )   I want to use those values because with each hit there will be a different json value  but, here I see we are explicitly proving the Json values

Comment: and  like i want to store that value in a val something ...and write that json to a kafka topic. ( I'm using docker-compose and have created topic locally )

Comment: Appreciate  your help!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overread the part that you want the json to be the "payload" of the POST. I don't have time to update my reply at the moment, but if you look at this example from the official zio quickstart repository, it shows a route where some json payload is POSTed: https://github.com/zio/zio-quickstart-restful-webservice/blob/master/src/main/scala/dev/zio/quickstart/users/UserApp.scala

Comment: yup..yeah currently reading that part, Thanksyou!